# Erro no Genymotion API

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

O problema ocorre quando eu tento executar os *APIs* de `level 26` em diante , já nos *APIs* de nível inferior ele roda super bem.
O erro é esse abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]